# Why is the Java Cryptography limited?

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm a bit new to cryptography and i'm wondering why there is a Limit for the Key size in Java?

It's only possible to use bigger Keys with especially installing the unlimited strength jurisdiction policy file...

Comment: You can download the [unlimited strength jars](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) and  replace your current jars with it in the $JRE_HOME/lib/security directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically because of politics. USA had an export restriction on encryption stronger than 40-bits back in the days, and even these days some governments don't allow strong encryption.

Oracle can distribute the default weak JCE version without being blocked by backwards governments, and make the policy files available as needed (those can then be blocked by the backwards governments).